# Unable to register a beacon due to Invalid field value for "advertisedId.id"

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I have obtained OAuth Access token with th following scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.beacon.registry

And using the access token received for authorizing Proximity Beacon APIs,

Now when I tried to register a beacon with the value mentioned at [google's documentation page](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register), It throws an error as follows,

```
{
error: {
code: 400
message: "Invalid value at 'beacon.advertised_id.id' (TYPE_BYTES), value was "scn3SDrgSD32rSEgv=""
status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
details: [1]
0:  {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
fieldViolations: [1]
0:  {
field: "beacon.advertised_id.id"
description: "Invalid value at 'beacon.advertised_id.id' (TYPE_BYTES), value was "scn3SDrgSD32rSEgv=""
}-
-
}-
-
}-
}
```

Comment: The error message appears to be dead on here — for whatever reason, that's not a valid base64-encoded ID. I tried to decode it on the command line with `openssl enc base64 -d <<< "scn3SDrgSD32rSEgv="` and it doesn't print anything. So, that doesn't appear to be a valid advertiserId … What function are you using to base64 encode the ID?

Comment: I am using Apache Commons codec Base64 class to generate Id                   String   bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64String("beacon" .getBytes());

Comment: Is this for an Eddystone beacon? Eddystone IDs are always 16 bytes, and when base64 encoded will always be roughly be 1/3 bigger than the original byte stream (base64 is 4:3) … a 16 byte ID should be roughly 22 chars or so. So there's definitely something wrong with the ID you're encoding if you're resulting base64 is only 18 chars. Where did you get this beaconID and can you see the value and verify it is 16 bytes? Don't forget you want to encode the BINARY version of this ID.

Comment: Thanks @MarcWan. I don't have any eddystone supported Beacons. I wanted to try out how to interact with Proximity beacon API. So I have used some random string as Id. By the way, provide me any sample beacon Id which would be acceptable by the API.

Comment: take your favourite code to generate a UUID, in binary form, and base64 encode that.  That should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AdverisedId` you pass to the register call must be valid — for Eddystone compatible beacons, the `id` field must be a 16-byte binary ID directly encoded as a base64 string, with the `type` field set to `"EDDYSTONE"`.

Comment: How to get AdvertiseId?